# How is short interest paid out, & is it possible to estimate the amount of short interest being paid?

Tags: stocks

I'm new to stocks & stackexchange. I was wondering if anyone could answer a few questions that I've been unable to find clear answers to in online sources. I appreciate any help.

**How is this interest paid out? :** Is short interest applied to the price at which the stock was originally shorted or the current price? Is it compounded? Is the broker paid by the shorter every day, week, month?

**Is it possible to estimate the short interest being paid out?:** Is there anyway to know or estimate when and at what price the stock was shorted & how much is total being paid out by the shorters in interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing two market metrics. As Joe stated in his answer, the Short % of Float is the number of shares shorted divided by the Float.  However, no one here has yet to explain how they arrive at the calculation offered on web sites like [Yahoo](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GME/key-statistics?p=GME) comes from.

When shares are shorted, the borrower pays a borrow rate to the lender. The borrow rate fluctuates and the amount due daily per share is the borrow rate times the closing share price divided by 365.  And yes, you pay it for the weekend as well.

I can't speak for all brokers but at my primary broker, it accrues daily and the total  is deducted from my account at the end of the month. It is not compounded.

The aggregate amount of interest owed on short stock each day would be the the above calculation times the number of short shares.

The borrow rate for the past 5 days at my broker (not including today) was:

```
 2/02 16.90 %
 2/01 18.81 %
 1/29 31.73 %
 1/28 37.12 %
 1/27 50.83 %
```

It is not possible to estimate  when and at what price stock was shorted.  Only the stock exchanges know that info.

Comment: Thanks! This clarifies my error in making the assumption that the ratio of shares shorted was also the interest rate.

Answer (score 2):

Interest here means something else.
It’s referring to the percent of shares that are shorted for a given stock. A stock can have more that 100% of its shares shorted as the shares bought from the short seller can be loaned out again.

Comment: The ironic thing about this question is that people that are short are paying interest. Man I don't even know what to do with this question.